# Difference between Spannable and String in android

Tags: android, spannable

Curiously want to know what is the purpose of `Spannable` in android. Isn't char array sufficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Spannable` allows to attach formatting information like bold, italic, ... to sub-sequences ("spans", thus the name) of the characters. It can be used whenever you want to represent "rich text".

The `Html` class provides an easy way to construct such text, for example:

```
Html.fromHtml("Text with <b>bold</b> and <em>italic</em>.")
```

Comment: exactly .. my question was any special case where we should use spannable and nothing else will work